# How to call in php an object in another object Facebook api url

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, object

I'm looking to use a url from an object...located in another object. 
The example here is to get the image url (located in object user, object picture, object data, url)

From the Console :

```
Object {id: "10153995795744213", picture: Object}
picture:Object
data:Object
    url:"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12963402_10153790184054213_2959661679219024256_n.jpg?oh=c04814c77c6e5e507b1e6dd08e40d50e&oe=582C5564"
```

Php

`$user=json_decode($_POST["user"],true);
     $id = $user["id"];
     $image = $user->picture->data->url;`

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.website.com/test.php",
                data: {user:JSON.stringify(user)},
```

I got the id correctly not the url

Do you know how can I get the URL ? :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: `var_dump($user)` and see what you got. your php doesn't correspond to the json you're posting.

Comment: array(5) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(17) "10153995795744213"

  ["picture"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["data"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["url"]=>
      string(146) "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12963402_10153790184054213_2959661679219024256_n.jpg?oh=c04814c77c6e5e507b1e6dd08e40d50e&oe=582C5564"
    }
  }
}

Comment: So you are able to access `id` correctly – but one line later, when it comes to `picture`, you suddenly forgot …?

Comment: Hi CBroe, sorry if my question seems simple to you. I'm new to coding and still learning (thanks to stackoverflow and the community). No need for mocking me

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the url by changing php :

```
$user=json_decode($_POST["user"],true);
$id = $user["id"];
$picture = $user["picture"];
$data = $picture["data"];
$url = $data["url"];
```